# Renaming a PHP variable on all relevant places, causes POST code to fail?

Tags: php, forms, submit, form-submit

I got this code:

```
<form action="go.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input name="a" type="hidden" value="1"  />
<input type="submit" class="something" value="GOOD">
</form>
```

and this is `go.php`:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['a']));

switch ($_POST['a']) {

    case "1":
        $param1 = "nice";
        break;

    case "2":
        $param1 = "great";
        break;

    default:
        $param1 = "other";
}

?>  
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $param1; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I submit the form this way, I'm getting "nice" message.
But If I change the name of `a` to `b` in all three relevant places, like this:

`<input name="b" type="hidden" value="1"  />`

`if(isset($_POST['b']));`

`switch ($_POST['b']) {`

I'm getting "other" message, instead of nice.

How could this be?

Comment: Should work, try echoing $_POST['b'] and see what it contains. Also, view source on the form html and make sure you see the b like you expect. Also, with the semi colon after the `if`, it's not doing anything based on the conditional.

Comment: all of the sudden its working without changing anything excpet b. I can't understand how could it be.

Comment: My best guess is you have a typo or haven't saved everything to the live code or something like that. Did you look into the things I mentioned above? Are you seeing `<input name="b"...` in the form view source? In the PHP try printing out both `$_POST['b']` and `$_POST['a']` to see if there is anything in either of them.

Comment: I've looked, and sometimes it is not posted at all, that's probably the key to the problem, can't figure out why it doesn't post though.

Comment: @smerny please see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665797/php-posting-into-modal-window-work-with-some-variable-and-with-some-not)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['a']));
```

should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['a'])){ // <-- curly brace, not semi-colon
```

I cannot imagine how this worked before you changed the `$_POST`

Comment: This shouldn't change anything though as if everything is as the OP said the var would always be set. I think the question is more "why isn't $_POST['b'] containing `1`?"

Comment: @smerny You might be right, you might also be wrong. The bottom line is: I **NEVER** trust non-curly-braced and non-indented code, period

Comment: thanks but the problem seem to be somewhere with the post, as I'm posting to a modal window, [I've opened another thread with more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665797/php-posting-into-modal-window-work-with-some-variable-and-with-some-not)

Answer (score 0):

You have a tiny syntax error in the handling section:

```
if(isset($_POST['a']));

switch ($_POST['a']) {
```

Should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['a'])){

    switch ($_POST['a']) {

    case "1":
    //same as before

    }//switch
}//end if - don't forget the closing bracket
```

Comment: This shouldn't change anything though as if everything is as the OP said the var would always be set. I think the question is more "why isn't $_POST['b'] containing `1`?"

Comment: thanks but the problem seem to be somewhere with the post, as I'm posting to a modal window, [I've opened another thread with more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665797/php-posting-into-modal-window-work-with-some-variable-and-with-some-not)